# Production Build Size (ExtReact)

Tags: reactjs, extjs, extreact

I just wanted to find out how can I reduce the build size of an ExtReact application? ,
I know the sencha command and webpack is already doing that by default built into the architecture but the build is still very large and the application takes time to load initially on low bandwidth.